# Missing parameter in WebService C# (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to call a web function but I dont know if i make any mistake.
this is the function that :

```
[WebMethod]
public string NumberOfHazardsToUser(string userid)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    command.CommandText = "select count(*) from Users_Hazards where User_ID = '" + userid + "'";
    command.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        if ((int)reader.GetValue(0) != 0)
        {
            int count = (int)reader.GetValue(0);
            command.Connection.Close();
            return json.Serialize(count);
        }
    }
    command.Connection.Close();
    return json.Serialize(0);
}
```

and this is how I call it

```
function getCountHazardsToUser() {
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: web + "/NumberOfHazardsToUser",
    method: "GET",
    data: '{"userid":"' + localStorage.getItem("id") + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var res = data.d;
        hazardsNumber = res;
    },
    error: function () {
        hazardsNumber = -1;
    }
});
```

}

and this is the respone 
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested you code with one modification (change `method:POST`) and working fine.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    url: web + "/NumberOfHazardsToUser",
    method: "POST",
    data: '{"userid":"' + localStorage.getItem("id") + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var res = data.d;
        hazardsNumber = res;
    },
    error: function () {
        hazardsNumber = -1;
    }
});
```

Please let me know if you need any help

[image]

Comment: his method is not a post

Comment: @Sajeetharan After making post I was able to recived the data

Comment: You are alright, i changed it to POST, I dont know why it needs to be not get.

Comment: @KaramHaj : you are posting the data to server

Comment: I got {"d":"5"}, Nice, the global value was not changed to 5 it's still 0

Comment: @santoshsingh i did